# What is the best practice to update / edit form fields in php and mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, sql-update

This may sound like a typical question, but I wasn't able to find decent answers on stackoverflow. I've already built adding and deleting items from the php form. Let's say I have a simple structure like this:

**Database**

```
|car_id(PK)|year  |   make   |   model   |  vin  |
--------------------------------------------------
|   1      | 2001 |  toyota  |  corolla  | 12345 |
|   2      | 1999 |  ford    |  fiesta   | 67890 |
|   3      | 2013 |  gmc     |  yukon    | abcde |
```

**Car Class**

```
class Car
{
   public car_id;
   public year;
   public make;
   public model;
   public vin; //unique, can only be one in DB

   function addCar(){...}
   function editCar(){...}
   function deleteCar(){...}
}
```

**PHP: cars.php?do=edit**

This is where I want to run functions from the class and display templates using smarty

**Viewer edit_cars.html**

When this page loads, it pulls all values from DB and creates forms with values already in them, user can overwrite the values or delete them.

**Question 1:**
Where should I check if vin(vehicle identification number, can only be one unique number in the database) matches the car already exists in the system? Car class or cars.php?

**Question 2:**
What is the best way to update records?

1. delete row and insert new one?
2. update ALL values, even if they didn't change
3. check fields that are different using javascript? (on change check
   values, if changed set some kind of var in PHP)
4. check fields that are different using php? (select old values and
   match them against form values after submit) Use some kind of PHP
   function to only update fields that changed

**Question 3:(this is more of a concern to me)**
After user submits the form, what should I do with their input:

1. when user leaves values as is and nothing has changed
2. when user deletes the value completely(such as "Make")
3. when user ONLY changes the letter from lower case to upper

I know these are a lot of questions, but I'm pretty sure a lot of people would benefit from this in the future when they are searching for these type of stuff.

Thank you so much for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Where should I check if vin matches the car already exists in the system? Car class or cars.php?`

The car class its self should only know about it's own properties and not if there are any other cars with the same VIN.

The restriction should be at database level as a unique key constraint. To avoid exceptions, you will need to check, outside of the car class, if an existing car is already registered within this VIN, prior to inserting the new car into the database.

`What is the best way to update records?`

Deleting the original row and then inserting a new one will cause you to have a different primary key id for that car. This will cause a problem with foreign keys as they will still reference the old id prior to the update. They could be updated, however I would strongly recommend avoiding this method.

Object Relational Mappers (ORM's) actually track the changes of objects once they have been loaded, this means that they can calculate and optimize the SQL query when they are actually executed.

For your needs however, updating all values (bar the id) will defiantly be your easiest option as there are negligible benefits of calculating changes (and its also unnecessary) when only performing a few queries or without an ORM.

`After user submits the form, what should I do with their input:`

All front end validation (that is any Javascript) will need to be replicated in the back end, server side. This is to avoid `SQL injection` and also to perform the required business logic. I.e `Number of wheels cannot be "bacon"`

Most of this you can cover on the client side, allowing the user to know (without a new HTTP request) that there is something wrong with the data they have entered. The inputs that you validate and how you represent these errors to the user is up to you and it will depend on the context of the data being entered.

What is **very** important is that you validate ALL the data independently of the javascript in PHP to avoid someone simply disabling javascript in their browser and `SQL injecting` into your database.

Comment: +1 for UNIQUE field for VIN number. I would +100 for bacon example if I could))) It's not exactly the answers I was looking for, but you've shared some very interesting info regarding MySQL structure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

I don't know what you mean here. Check if `vin` matches what? The associated `vin` number in the edit form?

Question 2:

It will be fastest to just send the changes to your server-side script as this is only one HTTP request, rather than checking first with Javascript, but this has a lot to with the user experience. Do you want your users to know they did something wrong or did not actually make a meaningful edit? If so, an AJAX call would probably work best.

Updating a row will definitely be faster than deleting one and then reinserting it.

Question 3:

a) I would say run your AJAX call anyway, why bother trying to do anything about this. Are you concerned about performance? If the user is stupid enough to submit a form after not doing anything then so be it.

b) What do you mean by this? You mean changes the `make` to a blank value? That would depend on your business logic? Is that not allowed? If so, you should probably do some form validation before submission to ensure that they cannot submit when they make a mistake like that.

c) This once again is determined by your business concerns.

Comment: Question 1: If there is same existing VIN in db, the system will not allow to write to database. VIN number for cars is unique through all of the manufacturers, it is like an identification for vehicles.

Comment: Question 3.3, What do I do if user changes "Rolls-royce" to "Rolls-Royce"? Is there a way I can identify changes ONLY in capitalization of the letter?

Comment: @Timur Once again, you have to decide what to do here. This is all about user experience. 2nd ques: Of course, write some code that compares each letter to both the lower case and upper case version.

Comment: I can write it myself, but I wasn't sure if there was already existing function that I can use in PHP, Mysql or js

Comment: @Timur Hmm maybe, I am not going to dig through the api for you. Look for the equivalent of `equalsIgnoreCase` of Java. PHP has so many functions it would not surprise me if they have it. Javascript probably does as well.